# C# : choosing the title and the extension of the archived file

Tags: c#, rar

I'm trying to copy a file to a rar archive.
it works with this code,

```cs
            using (FileStream fStream = File.Open(dest, FileMode.Create))
            {
                GZipStream obj = new GZipStream(fStream, CompressionMode.Compress);

                byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes(src);
                obj.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);

                obj.Close();
                obj.Dispose();
            }
```

but i need to choose the name/extension of the file in the archive independently
What do i need to?

Comment: Do you need to rename the archive or the files in the archive?  Either way, why not rename in code before creating the archive(if needing to rename contents files) or rename the archive file after(if need to change actual archive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, just because you're not creating a rar archive at all, it's instead a gzip, which is a very simple compresed stream and very little extra metadata, unless more serious formats like rar, zip or 7z.

You'll most likely want to control the name of the compressed file by adding a .gz extension. For example, if the original is "SomeText.txt", output it as "SomeText.txt.gz".